# URIBuilder and list query params

Tags: java, web-services, rest, query-string, uribuilder

I'm using apache **[URIBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html)** to build a query string for a **GET method** of a Rest service.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/remote") 
    public Return getTest(Ordine ordine) throws Exception{
        ...
    }
```

This is the input object:

```
public class Ordine{    
    private List<String> codici;
    //..get...set..
}
```

I cannot understand how to set this string list as query params.

I tried to set param twice:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder()
                .setHost("localhost")
                .setPort(8080)
                .setScheme("http")
                .setPath("/remote")
                .setParameter("codici", codicilist.get(0))
                .setParameter("codici", codicilist.get(1));
```

But the first param it will be overwrite from the second.
Then I tried to append [] in the param name:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder()
                .setHost("localhost")
                .setPort(8080)
                .setScheme("http")
                .setPath("/remote")
                .setParameter("codici[]", codicilist.get(0))
                .setParameter("codici[]", codicilist.get(1));
```

But it is simply sent with name "codici[]" and the first param is overwritten.
Then I tried a comma separated values:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder()
                .setHost("localhost")
                .setPort(8080)
                .setScheme("http")
                .setPath("/remote")
                .setParameter("codici", String.join(",",codicilist));
```

But if fails... how can I set a list of param?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your expample, just use `addParameter` instead of `setParameter`. `setParameter` will override your parameter if it already exists. `addParameter` will add a new one (ignoring existing ones).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [addParameters](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html#addParameters(java.util.List)) method.

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder()
            .setHost("localhost")
            .setPort(8080)
            .setScheme("http")
            .setPath("/remote").addParameters(buildParamList())
```

Then get all `codici` parameter values with a helper method which will build a list of  `NameValuePair` pairs.

```
private List<NameValuePair> buildParamList() {
    List<NameValuePair> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : codici) {
        output.add(new BasicNameValuePair("codici", string));
    }
    return output;
}
```

So you'll get an output similar to http://localhost:8080/remote?codici=codici1&codici=codici2&codici=codici3 given that `codici` list contains `codici1`, `codici2`, `codici3`